# Procedure is giving error if we have space in column value

Tags: mysql

I have below database table :
Table name - dim_module

```
id       Creation_Date         Goals  Alternative    Value
-----------------------------------------------------------
1   2014-04-17 10:09:30         G1         A         0.86
2   2014-04-17 10:09:30         G1         B         0.87
3   2014-04-17 10:09:30         G2         A         0.5
4   2014-04-17 10:09:30         G2         B         0
```

I am using below procedure for getting desired output

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `stmt`()
BEGIN
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(goals = ''',
      goals,
      ''', round(value, 2), NULL)) AS ',
      goals
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM sgwebdb.dim_module;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT alternative, ', @sql, ' FROM sgwebdb.dim_module GROUP BY alternative');

prepare stmt from @sql;

END
```

I am getting below output with above procedure.

```
Alternative    G1       G2
-----------------------------
 A            0.86      0.50    
 B            0.87      0.00
```

But if Goals column value is having space in first table(dim_module) like G1 is G 1
Check first row Goals column in below table.

id       Creation_Date         Goals  Alternative    Value
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    1   2014-04-17 10:09:30      G 1        A         0.86
    2   2014-04-17 10:09:30      G1         B         0.87
    3   2014-04-17 10:09:30      G2         A         0.5
    4   2014-04-17 10:09:30      G2         B         0

then it is giving below error

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1,MAX(IF(goals = 'Goal1', round(value, 2), NULL)) AS Goal1,MAX(IF(goals = 'Goal2' at line 1
```

Please help me for this error.

Comment: What is it that you _want_ to happen? Should it ignore the space or treat `G1` and `G 1` entirely separate or...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I just want to show same name whatever is there in first table.if G 1 then it should show G 1 if it is G1 in first table then procedure should give G1 as an output.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson basically it is not accepting spaces in output.i want to give space also.if column value is having space then it gives above error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use spaces in your field names, you need to use backticks to quote them;

Replace

```
  ''', round(value, 2), NULL)) AS ',                 -- Will use field name G 1, breaks
  goals
```

with

```
  ''', round(value, 2), NULL)) AS `',                -- Will use field name `G 1`, works
  goals, '`'
```

which will quote the field name and allow spaces.

Comment: @xpy The comments below the question seem to say that the op wants them to be separate groups.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I am just testing your solution,it seems to be desired solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue there in the field name after `AS` keyword. If the field name has spaces inside it you should quote it. Try this:

```
CONCAT(
  'MAX(IF(goals = ''',
  goals,
  ''', round(value, 2), NULL)) AS ',
  '`', goals,'`'
)
```

Comment: This is also a desired answer but bro I can mark only on as answer,thx a ton